# How to read an Integer number in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly and making a program that will read a number in assembly ,I am able to read it from keyboard but facing issues while printing it on screen ,below is code

```
section .data
x db "number is =%d",10,0
y db "number is =%d",10,0
section .text
global main
 extern printf
 extern scanf
 extern read
 lea ebx ,[c1]
 push ebx
 push x
 call scanf
 mov ecx,c1

 push ecx
 push y
 call printf
 add esp,16
 ret
```

What is best way of read an integer number in assembly?

Comment: Shouldn't you be pushing the value at `c1` rather than c1's address when calling `printf`?

Comment: @Michael you mean to say mov ecx,[c1]or how do I push value of C1??

Comment: Either that or `push dword [c1]`

Comment: Thanks @Michael it worked well ,Couple of point would like to ask .lea ebx ,[c1] I thought we do need to pass the address of c1 to stack as we do in C langugae scanff(%d",&c1) and Second point is what happen if we call read after call to scanf ,Is call read will put value read by scanf to eax??

Comment: `scanf` needs to write the values it reads from stdin somewhere, which is why you have to pass pointers (addresses) to it. `printf` doesn't need to know the address of any of its arguments (except for the format string), so they are passed by value.